# How do I modify Google Chrome user agent string with Robot Framework

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I tried to modify the user agent string using `Open Browser` with `desired_capabilities` and discovered that Chrome does not support that technique any more.

After much searching and reading I discovered that there was a new version of Selenium2library that had a new keyword `Create Webdriver` that is supposed to address this issue.

I modified their example to suite my needs. But no matter what I do, it does not modify the user agent string.

I get no errors, no warnings, no nothing, except a perfectly working browser without a modified user agent string.

I tried to modify other options like `--start-maximized` with the same result, i.e. no result at all.

Excerpt from keyword that opens Google Chrome and (allegedly) modifies the user agent string:

```
${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()   sys, selenium.webdriver
${options.add_argument}=    Set Variable    user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36 System/ComputerId" 
Create WebDriver    Chrome  chrome_options=${options}   
Go To   http://www.useragentstring.com
```

Fashioned after the example given here (at the bottom of the page):

https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/issues/225

My software setup:

- Google Chrome 31.0.1650.59
- Selenium 2.39.0
- Selenium2library 1.5
- Robot Framework 2.8.3
- Robot Framework Ride 1.2.2

So what is the problem?

Comment: A solution to this problem seems as elusive as a unicorn at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more tinkering and reading I managed to figure out a way to get the example working.

Instead of using `${options.add_argument}=` I used `Call Method    ${options}    add_argument`.

```
${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36 System/ComputerId
Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}    
Go To    http://www.useragentstring.com
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried setting up user agent in chrome using RF and working fine for me below snippet...!

```
${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
${userAgent}=  set variable  --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19"
Call Method    ${options}  add_argument  ${userAgent}
Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why the `Set Variable` method works here vs the suggestion provided by Mats. This worked for me though I am not entirely sure why the user agent as variable works vs. passing it as a direct flag/switch argument.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem. i tried running your code but no luck in making it work. It just says that the user agent is not defined. I have browsed and came across this code, but unfortunately is written in python:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19" }
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
```